# How not to change the first default function parameter when changing the others

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I define a function with 2 or more default parameters, how can I change only the second or third (etc.) one when calling it? eg.:

```
>>>def f(a=10,b=5,c=7):
       return (a*b*c)
```

How can I change the values of b or c if I want to keep the original value of a?

Comment: Just supply the name for it, `f(b=30)` or `f(c=20)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign variables by name instead of position:

```
f(b=1, c=2)
f(0, c=2) # sets a=0 and c=2
```

Alternatively you can use key word arguments:

```
kwargs = { 'b': 1, 'c': 2 }
f(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function and pass arguments by name:

```
i = f(b=35,c=76)  # sets b and c while doing nothing to a
```